# Proving a set doesn't span $\Bbb R^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I'm given the set $\mathbb \{(1,-1,5),(3,1,3),(1,2,-4)\}$ and asked to show it does *not* span $\mathbb R^3$. I make the following system of equations:

$$\mathit r+3s+t=a\\
-r+s+2t=b \\
5r+3s-4t = c$$
Putting it into the augmented matrix:
$$ \left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  1&3&1&a\\
  -1&1&2&b\\
  5&3&-4&c
\end{array}
\right] $$
I can't seem to row-reduce it down to the point where I get all zeroes at the bottom. Is there some other way of demonstrating this?

Comment: You don't need the fourth column. Row-reducing the $3 \times 3$ is enough. Alternatively, you could show that the determinant of that $3 \times 3$ matrix is $0$, so the matrix is not invertible, hence not full rank.

Comment: If you know some dimension theorems, you can say that the given set of $3$ vectors in a $3$-dimensional space is either both spanning and linearly independent (i.e. a basis) or neither spanning nor linearly independent. So, if you show that the vectors are linearly dependent, then that proves they are not spanning.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Did you mean given the set $\mathbb \{(1,-1,5),(\color{red}{3,1,3}),(1,2,-4)\}$ ?

Comment: I'm so sorry yes. I've edited the question.

Comment: $\frac53 (1, -1, 5) + \frac43 (1, 2, -4) = (3, 1, 3)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't say what went wrong when you tried to row reduce the matrix. That's a straightforward way to proceed, so let's do it. Starting with the vectors assembled into columns as you did in the OP:
$$ \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 3 & 1 \\
-1 & 1 & 2 \\
5 & 3 & -4
\end{pmatrix}$$
Add the first row to the second row, and subtract 5 times the first row from the third row to obtain:
$$ \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 3 & 1 \\
0 & 4 & 3 \\
0 & -12 & -9
\end{pmatrix}$$
You can already see that the rows are not linearly independent: the third row is -3 times the second row. So add three times the second row to the third row to produce the desired row of zeros:
$$ \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 3 & 1 \\
0 & 4 & 3 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$
The first two rows are clearly linearly independent, so the rank of the matrix is 2.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like I need more practice row-reducing.

Answer (score 1):

You don’t want the reduced augmented matrix to have a zero row. That would mean that there is a solution for every combination of values of $a$, $b$ and $c$ (in fact, an infinite number of them), in which case the set of vectors *does* span $\mathbb R^3$, which is exactly the opposite of what you’re trying to prove.

Instead, after a few row-reduction steps, one reaches $$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}1&3&1&a\\0&4&3&a+b\\0&0&0&-2a+3b+c\end{array}\right].$$ Unless $2a-3b-c=0$, this system is inconsistent: there’s no linear combination of the three vectors that is equal to $(a,b,c)^T$, therefore the set does not span $\mathbb R^3$. For instance, $(0,0,1)^T$ doesn’t lie in their span.

Answer (score 0):

Because $$0(1,-1,5)+(1,2,-4)=(1,2,-4)$$ gives $$\dim sp\{(1,-1,5),(1,2,-4),(1,2,-4)\}<3.$$

Comment: Come again? $\ $

Comment: There was a mistake in the question; it has been corrected now